# SQL Server reorder sequence number when records are moved up or down

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have one table in SQL Server with `Id, Plan_Id, sequence_no` and the following data.

```
Id          Plan_Id      sequence_no
----------- ------------ -----------
1132507748  1167096719   0
1102670655  1167096719   1
1166210290  1167096719   2
```

so on web site I am listing these records based on **sequence_no**. User can sort these records using drag & drop.

What I want here is, when user drag 1th record to 0th position then I want to reorder all records in table. I have Id,Plan_id and new sequence_no as parameter to procedure. I tried below code but it won't worked.

```
update dbo.planRecords
set sequence_no = sequence_no+1
where plan_id = @plan_id and sequence_no >= @newPosition
```

How can I reorder these records ?

Comment: Not sure if its a typo in your post but your column is called sequence_no in your query and sequance_no in your table definition?

Comment: Do you really want to be churning through all of your rows every time (from the user's perspective) they change just one row? There are ways of *recording* sequences that will normally only require changes to that row (or one or two others), and you can then always have a `ROW_NUMBER()` expression in your `SELECT` if you need to *show* sequence numbers which are 0-based, all integers, no gaps, if required.

Comment: @SEarle1986 Please see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know the old position before you can move items around. And your logic needs to be different depending on whether the item was moved up or down. Rough outline of the process (not tested) is as follows:

```
DECLARE @Id INT = 1100000004; -- this id
DECLARE @NewPosition INT = 1; -- needs to have this position

WITH RowToMove AS (
    -- using cte instead of variables
    SELECT Plan_Id, sequence_no AS OldPosition
    FROM planRecords
    WHERE Id = @Id
), RowsToUpdate AS (
    -- columns used inside set and where clause of the update statement
    SELECT Id, sequence_no, OldPosition
    FROM planRecords
    CROSS JOIN RowToMove
    -- select rows that belong to same category and position between old and new
    WHERE planRecords.Plan_Id = RowToMove.Plan_Id AND sequence_no BETWEEN 
        CASE WHEN OldPosition < @NewPosition THEN OldPosition ELSE @NewPosition END AND
        CASE WHEN OldPosition > @NewPosition THEN OldPosition ELSE @NewPosition END
)
UPDATE RowsToUpdate SET sequence_no = CASE
    WHEN Id = @Id THEN @NewPosition -- this is the row we are moving
    WHEN OldPosition < @NewPosition THEN sequence_no - 1 -- row was moved down, move other rows up
    WHEN OldPosition > @NewPosition THEN sequence_no + 1 -- row was moved up, move other rows down
END;
```

Demo on DBFiddle [using variables](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5b4a6a6de8f3af7d8603e1da3f60285c), [using CTE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6cb0c1c2a91e3c06466d8e7ecca85ee1)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Is there any other way if I don't have old position ?

Comment: You can simply select the old position before updating as shown in the above example. There might be workarounds but they will result in a hard to understand query. Remember that you need to add or subtract 1 and only change the rows that needs to be updated, and for that, keeping track of old position is required.

Comment: I tried this but it is not changing 0th position records to 1st. In my example I dragged 1102670655(1st) to 1102670655(0th). so record 1132507748 should changed to 1st position.

Comment: My bad. I should have added that you also need the `Id` of the element being moved. I'll revise the query.

Comment: @AjayPunekar see revised answer.

Comment: Now it's working. It was due to plan_id which are same for all records.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to not use int, but decimal. That way, you only need to know the two closest siblings of the record, and only need to change the value of the sequence_no to a number between them.

For instance, if you have the following records in your database:

```
Id          Plan_Id      sequance_no
----------- ------------ -----------
1132507748  1167096719   1.0
1102670655  1167096719   2.0
1166210290  1167096719   3.0
1132507763  1167096719   4.0
1102670623  1167096719   5.0
1166210299  1167096719   6.0
```

and you want to move record 5.0 to between 1.0 and 2.0, all you need to do is to update it's sequence_no to 1.5:

```
Id          Plan_Id      sequance_no
----------- ------------ -----------
1132507748  1167096719   1.0
1102670623  1167096719   1.5
1102670655  1167096719   2.0
1166210290  1167096719   3.0
1132507763  1167096719   4.0
1166210299  1167096719   6.0
```

[Decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) supports up to 38 digits so you can use up to 37 digits to the right of the decimal point, so even if you have a lot of changes in the order of the records, I'm pretty sure you will not have to worry about running out of slots.

If you want to display the order of the records in round numbers, you can always use `row_number() over(order by sequence_no)` to get a nice int values display.

Comment: I am showing these records sequence on web portal. so that user can drag/drop

Comment: I don't see how that information is relevant to the storage solution. All you need to know is what record was moved and to where... Of course, you can simply re-calculate the order on the client side, and send it to the database to be updated.

Comment: You'll could up with values such as `1.99999952316284179688` after 20 or so inserts at second position.

Comment: @SalmanA actually, the value will get closer to 1.0 as you insert more and more values. - suppose you are inserting a value that is half way between the existing records - so the first would be `1.5`, second would be `1.25`, third would be `1.0625` and so on. by the time you've moved 20 records to the second position (assuming once a record is in the second position it doesn't get moved unless pushed away), you'll end up with `1,00000047683715820312`.