# SQL Server - How to keep SQL int column in numeric order with no gaps

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column (TaskPosition) which keeps track of a records position in an html table. It is vital that the values in this column are kept in numeric order with no gaps, even if there is a deletion.

```
TaskID  TaskName    TaskPosition
1   Project Planning    1
2   Define Requirements 2
3   Develop Options     3
4   Finalise Solution   4
```

If I delete the record where TaskPosition = 3 then I want the TaskPosition column to be

```
TaskID  TaskName    TaskPosition
1   Project Planning    1
2   Define Requirements 2
4   Finalise Solution   3
```

Comment: What if generate TaskPosition with no gaps, only at read (SELECT). updating whole table for every delete, may be not so good idea

Comment: It's a bad design, what happens if you've 500,000 rows and delete task position 3? You'll have to update a further 499,997 rows.

Comment: Instead of saving the column - always recalculate it with ROW_NUMBER when selecting.

Comment: I'd usually recommend a `float` column for this, and as others say, generate the integer using a `ROW_NUMBER()` expression during `SELECT`. `float` lets you easily *rearrange* rows without need to renumber rows not directly impacted by the move too.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650318/sql-server-reorder-sequence-number-when-records-are-moved-up-or-down

Answer (score 1):

> generate the integer using a `ROW_NUMBER()` expression during 
>     `SELECT` @Damien_The_Unbeliever

```
create table #noGapInt (TaskID int identity(1,1), TaskName  varchar(10), TaskPosition int)

insert #noGapInt (TaskName , TaskPosition) values ('a',1),('a',2),('a',3),('a',4),('a',5),('a',6)

select * from #noGapInt

delete from #noGapInt where TaskPosition = 4

select * from #noGapInt

select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by TaskID) TaskPosition from #noGapInt
```