# Reset the numeric sequence of a column after deleting a row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have seen many solutions for reseeding an identity column after deleting a row. I'm needing to reset a numeric sequence from a column that's not an identity column, however.

```
+------+---------+----------+
| group| user    | sequence |
+------+---------+----------+
|   1  | barney  |     1    |
|   1  | andy    |     2    |
|   1  | odis    |     3    |
|   1  | opie    |     4    |
|   2  | beaver  |     1    |
|   2  | wally   |     2    |
|   2  | eddie   |     3    |
+------+---------+----------+
```

So, if I delete odis, the new sequence needs to look like this:

```
+------+---------+----------+
| group| user    | sequence |
+------+---------+----------+
|   1  | barney  |     1    |
|   1  | andy    |     2    |
|   1  | opie    |     3    |
|   2  | beaver  |     1    |
|   2  | wally   |     2    |
|   2  | eddie   |     3    |
+------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: If its not an identity column then how are you currently generating the sequence?

Comment: So if you delete `odis` after having inserted `opie` you want to regenerate the entire sequence for that table?

Comment: @DaleBurrell, Yes, but I want to regenerate the sequence for group 1 only.

Comment: There is no function to do this, so you will have to code it, maybe the best way to do it is by creating a trigger to handle the delete, this will allow you to know which record was deleted and regenerate the sequence manually

Comment: In that case, why bother storing the sequence, when you can just generate it in any query via ROW_NUMBER() partitioning by group.

Comment: @DaleBurrell, I am reordering the sequence number as in the solution found here:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650318/sql-server-reorder-sequence-number-when-records-are-moved-up-or-down). It works great for reordering but I was having an issue when a row is deleted from the table.

Comment: We're clearly talking about "Otis Campbell" with a "T". :)

Comment: @shawnt00 Yes, you are right about that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of resetting (a potentially significant part of) the column values when deletion happen, you could build a view view on top of the table that computes the sequence on the fly.

Either using a sort on the user name (however this means that the sequence could change when a usernmae is updated):

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS
SELECT
    group,
    user,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY group ORDER BY user) sequence
FROM mytable t
```

Or better yet, with a sort based on the original sequence:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS
SELECT
    group,
    user,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY group ORDER BY sequence) sequence
FROM mytable t
```

Comment: Are you sure about `ORDER BY [User]`?

Comment: @Sami: if we follow the logic of creating a view, I am unsure how important it is to retain the original sequence. But sure, it could be better to sort by sequence. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solves your problem:

```
with tbl2(grp, usr, seq) as
(
select grp, usr,
    row_number() over(partition by grp order by seq) as seq
from tbl1
)
update tbl1
set seq = t2.seq
from tbl1 t1
join tbl2 t2 on t2.grp = t1.grp and t2.usr = t1.usr
where t2.seq != t1.seq
```